# How to get the value of an element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the text (1, 2, 3...) of li elements on each click on the anchor tag 'show' via jQuery but can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I'm working with:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="item_id">1</li>
<a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="item_id">2</li>
<a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="item_id">3</li>
<a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
/**This shows all values on each click and not only the current one**/
$("a.show").click(function(){

  $('li.item_id').each(function() {
      var item_id = $(this).text();
          alert(testimonial_id);                    
        });

});

/**This shows the first value on each click and not only the current one**/
$("a.show").click(function(){

    var item_id = $("li.item_id").text();
    alert(item_id);

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid. Only `li` or `ol` elements can be children of a `ul`. The `a` element needs to be moved

Comment: Thank you for the note. I did it like that mainly to avoid dealing with a styling issue for now.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `$(this).closest('ul').find('li.item_id')`

1. onclick target the parent element using [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function.
2. Then [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the `li.item_id`.finally return the text

```js
$("a.show").click(function() {
  let item_id = $(this).closest('ul').find('li.item_id').text();
  console.log(item_id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item_id">1</li>
  <a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="item_id">2</li>
  <a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="item_id">3</li>
  <a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>
Javascript:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the sibling through [`.siblings(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/); then use `.text()` to pull out its `innerText` property.

```js
$("a.show").click(function() {
  const itemId = $(this).siblings('li.item_id').text();
  console.log(itemId)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item_id">1</li>
  <a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="item_id">2</li>
  <a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="item_id">3</li>
  <a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `prev()`.

> The [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method searches for the predecessor of each of these
>   elements in the DOM tree.

```js
$("a.show").click(function() {
  let item_id = $(this).prev('li.item_id').text();
  console.log(item_id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item_id">1</li>
  <a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="item_id">2</li>
  <a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="item_id">3</li>
  <a class="show" href="#">SHOW</a>
</ul>
Javascript:
```